# simple ksh shell script fails when comparing numbers

Tags: shell, ksh

I wrote a shell script that does a comparison of two variables that contain numbers. If the variables contain the same number the script runs fine. However if the first variable(number) is greater then the second variable(number) it fails.

Here is the shell script. Note: LST1=51228, LST2=34152

```
#!/bin/ksh

LST1=`cat /tmp/1.lst`
LST2=`cat /tmp/2.lst`
echo $LST1 $LST2

if [[ $LST2 -gt $LST1 ]];then
 cat $LST2 >/tmp/0.cmp
else
 echo "do nothing" >/tmp/0.cmp
fi
```

Here are the run-time errors:

```
#!/bin/ksh 
LST1=`cat /tmp/1.lst`
+ + cat /tmp/1.lst
LST1=34152
LST2=`cat /tmp/2.lst`
+ + cat /tmp/2.lst
LST2=51228
echo $LST1 $LST2
+ echo 34152 51228
34152 51228

if [[ $LST2 -gt $LST1 ]];then
 cat $LST2 >/tmp/0.cmp
else
 echo "do nothing" >/tmp/0.cmp
fi
+ [[ 51228 -gt 34152 ]]
+ cat 51228
+ 1> /tmp/0.cmp
cat: Cannot open 51228: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
cat $LST2 >/tmp/0.cmp
```

unless you have a file called 51228 should probably be

```
       echo $LST2 >/tmp/0.cmp
```

You want the contents of the shell variable LST2, not the contents of a file named by LST2

Comment: That worked. I overlooked the obvious using the echo command. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if [[ $LST2 -gt $LST1 ]];  then
    echo $LST2 >/tmp/0.cmp
...
```

The `cat` command tries to open a file with the value provided.

Using `echo` will print the value into the destined file.